# remove specific group memberships large list of users in a CSV file

Tags: performance, powershell, csv

I am able to remove all membership for users. I have tried script so far like below. My question is :I've been looking for a script that would remove specific group membership. Also ,we have  a large list of users in a CSV file .

```
$RemovefromGroups = $UserisMember.memberOf | ForEach-Object {Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like '*group*'"}
```

Error message:

```
    Get-ADGroup : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'CN=group_name,OU=GP,DC=contoso,DC=com'.
At line:1 char:73
+ $RemovefromGroups = $UserisMember.memberOf | ForEach-Object {Get-ADGroup <<<<  $_ -Filter "name -like '*group*'"}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

Code:

```
#import csv info for use in foreach loop
$csv = import-csv "c:\temp\a.csv" #have header column for "userinput"

foreach ($v in $csv) {

  $userinput = $v.userinput

  # Remove user from all AD groups
  $UserisMember = Get-ADUser $userinput -Properties memberOf
  $RemovefromGroups = $UserisMember.memberOf | ForEach-Object {Get-ADGroup $_ }
  $RemovefromGroups | ForEach-Object { Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $UserisMember -Confirm:$false}          
}
```

Comment: Your error message seems to be incomplete. Could you post the complete error, please?

Comment: Since you know a partial name of the group just gather them all `$RemovefromGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like '*SSL_VPN*'"`. And do this outside of the `foreach` loop

Comment: The first positional parameter for the `Get-ADGroup` cmdlet is the `-Identity` parameter and indeed you do not supply that. Inside the `ForEach-Object` loop, use the `$_` automatic variable like `ForEach-Object { $_ | Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like '*SSL_VPN*'"}` or `ForEach-Object { Get-ADGroup -Identity $_.DistinghuishedName -Filter "name -like '*SSL_VPN*'"}`. See [Get-ADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroup?view=win10-ps#required-parameters)

Comment: @Theo  I am getting `Get-ADGroup : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Where-Object` clause to the end of this pipeline:

```
$RemovefromGroups = $UserisMember.memberOf | ForEach-Object {Get-ADGroup $_ }
```

so it becomes

```
$RemovefromGroups = $UserisMember.memberOf | ForEach-Object {Get-ADGroup $_ } | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*SSL_VPN*'}
```

Comment: Thanks man. its works very well. My last question is :  we have a large list of users in a CSV file. How can I tune this script ? Because those users have multiple groups

Comment: @Arbelac calculate all the removals up front and then call `Remove-ADGroupMember` once per group, rather than once per membership